# Unwanted repeats of ajax/jquery POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm running into an issue where my post requests are being repeated for reasons I cannot comprehend. I'm using a jQuery POST request to submit a form to a php script to insert it into an SQL database.

It only happens on some occasions and not consistently. 9/10 times it works as intended,  but sometimes the ajax call is repeated 2 or 3 times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqAr.jpg)

repeating block of code:

function submitLog(){

```
let log = document.getElementById('logContent').value;
let project = document.getElementById('logger_active_project').innerHTML;
let category = document.getElementById('categorySelect').value;
let projectID = document.getElementById('logger_active_project_id').value;
let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.disabled = true;

console.log('starting ajax post request');

$.post('./includes/logger/scripts/add_log.php', {
    log:log,
    project:project,
    category:category,
    project_id:projectID

}, function(data, status){
    document.getElementById('logContent').value= "";
    submit.disabled = false;
    console.log('ajax callback fired.' + data);
    
})
```

}
EDIT:

It seems to only be happening when used with the following function:

function submitLogByEntering(){
let log = document.getElementById('logContent');

```
log.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      // Cancel the default action, if needed
      event.preventDefault();
      submitLog();
    }
  });
}
```

When using the button to duplicate the issue i can not get it to repeat.

Thanks a bunch in advance for any tips to get me in the right direction to fix this hot mess!

Comment: hi, have you made sure that it is fired 2-3 times? Sometimes browser console is not your best friend. If you try it 10 times  and you see that 1 time it was repeated 3 times, are there 12 added objects on the database instead of 10? If not, then your script is ok, if there are 12, then please provide more information about your code.

Comment: It does indeed fire multiple times. DB shows identical posts with just an incremented ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will most likely be down to the listener for `submitLog()`.

Check that you're not using a listener that would multi fire.

If it's to much to check just set a test variable outside of your `submitLog()`, set it to true and test if true then fire the ajax. Then set it to false after your post request. This will stop duplicate button presses etc from happening or anything funny in the listener.

If you need to re fire the function set a timeout on the variable (Or set it after ajax completion) to reset it back to true.

EXAMPLE:

```js
    var test = true;
    
    function submitLog() {
    
        if (test) {
    
            let log = document.getElementById('logContent').value;
            let project = document.getElementById('logger_active_project').innerHTML;
            let category = document.getElementById('categorySelect').value;
            let projectID = document.getElementById('logger_active_project_id').value;
            let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
            submit.disabled = true;
    
            console.log('starting ajax post request');
    
            $.post('./includes/logger/scripts/add_log.php', {
                log: log,
                project: project,
                category: category,
                project_id: projectID
    
            }, function (data, status) {
                document.getElementById('logContent').value = "";
                submit.disabled = false;
                console.log('ajax callback fired.' + data);
    
            });
    
            test = false;
            setTimeout(function () {
                test = true;
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Wakka, thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the main post to include the function that handles the event listener and (seems) to be causing the issue. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Ah you're using keyup, The problem with key listeners is they repeat if the key is held down and in other ways too (The OS and other factors have influence here). If you set a console.log on the keypress listener for the enter key aka 13 you will probably see it fire multiple times. It's really common. You will have to go down the variable route like I said. This is a common way to negate this issue.

Comment: So i'd have to create a variable that's true allowing the function to fire, upon the button press it goes to false and then for example with a setInterval() turn it back to true to allow it to fire once more? Not entirely sure I fully understand how to implement your solution. 
Thanks a lot for the direction so far though!

Comment: @dkvdev Ill update my answer with it

Comment: thank you ever so much! I've come up with a fix in the meantime to check the DB's last record for duplicate results. But it feels more like a hack then an elegant solution.

Comment: @dkvdev that's it updated.

Comment: Your a hero! Will fiddle around with this in just a moment!